# How do I show the value of a #define at compile time in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, pragma

So far I've got as far as:

```
#define ADEFINE "23"
#pragma message ("ADEFINE" ADEFINE)
```

Which works, but what if ADEFINE isn't a string?

```
#define ADEFINE 23
#pragma message ("ADEFINE" ADEFINE)
```

causes:

> warning: malformed ‘#pragma message’, ignored

Ideally I'd like to be able to deal with any value, including undefined.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To display macros which aren't strings, [stringify the macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/cpp/Stringification.html):

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) XSTRINGIFY(s)
#define XSTRINGIFY(s) #s

#define ADEFINE 23
#pragma message ("ADEFINE=" STRINGIFY(ADEFINE))
```

If you have/want [boost](http://www.boost.org), you can use [boost stringize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/headers/stringize.html) to do it for you:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#define ADEFINE 23
#pragma message ("ADEFINE=" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(ADEFINE))
```

Comment: Well, I don't think my client is going to be very happy to have that added as a dependency, but that looks like an existence proof. Perhaps I should go and have a look at stringize.hpp

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden I updated the answer with how to do it without boost (or any other library).

Comment: Your link is no longer active: "stringify the macro"

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this will do what you want, but if you're only interested in this to debug the occasional macro problem (so it's not something you need displayed in a message for each compile), the following might work for you. Use gcc's `-E -dD` option to dump `#define` directives along with preprocessing output.  Then pipe that through `grep` to see only the lines you want:

```
// test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define ADEFINE "23"
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#undef ADEFINE
#define ADEFINE 42
    return 0;
}
```

The command `gcc -E -dD -c test.c | grep ADEFINE` shows:

```
#define ADEFINE "23"
#undef ADEFINE
#define ADEFINE 42
```